# React NavigatorIOS not updating title on replace()

Tags: react-native

I'm using a NavigatorIOS component in my root component, and want to toggle between a login an register screen:

```
navToLogin() {
    this.refs.nav.replace({
        title: "Login",
        component: LoginScene,
        rightButtonTitle: "Sign Up",
        onRightButtonPress: this.navToRegister.bind(this)
    });
}

navToRegister() {
    this.refs.nav.replace({
        title: "Sign Up",
        component: RegisterScene,
        rightButtonTitle: "Login",
        onRightButtonPress: this.navToLogin.bind(this)
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <NavigatorIOS
            ref = "nav"
            style={styles.navigator}
            initialRoute={{
                component: LoginScene,
                title: "Login",
                rightButtonTitle: "Sign Up",
                onRightButtonPress: this.navToRegister.bind(this)
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Although the view is updated properly, the title and rightButton do not change after the *nav.replace()* invocation. When I'm using *nav.push()* everything works as expected.

Am I using this component wrong somehow?

Comment: Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/894

Comment: ...which was actually a duplicate of https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/476

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using it wrong, this is a bug NavigatorIOS. If you can it's probably worth using Navigator instead as that's better supported (Facebook are actually using it themselves internally)