# react-native NavigatorIOS is not working as expected

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, mobile-application

I am implementing a practice application in react-native for IOS. I am using NavigatorIOS for navigation. I want to remove first route from navigation stack after successful login so that user won't come back. I am using `.replace()` function for this purpose and it replaces the route but navigation title remains unchanged.

Here are Images and related code to explain scenario.

1. Login screen

   `<NavigatorIOS
   style={styles.container}
   initialRoute={{
   title: 'LOGIN',
   component: LoginScreen
   }}/>`

[image]

2. After successful login app navigates to home screen which should have title 'HOME' as specified in code

   `this.props.navigator.replace({
   title: 'HOME',
   component: HomeScreen,
   passProps: {token: responseData.token}
   });`

[image]

3. Next navigating to news, it still shows login on the back button.
   I just used `push()` method to push new view to stack.

   [image]
4. Here is the main issue I am concerned with and cannot understand why this is happening. 
   When is press back button viz '< LOGIN' it navigates to home screen and its title also changes to "HOME".

[image: on returning back to home screen from child view]

I do not get this behavior. Does anyone have idea why it is happening and how can I fix this thing. Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767977/react-navigatorios-not-updating-title-on-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known RN bug. You can track it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/476).

I suggest you use [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content) instead.

Comment: can you point me to some example of usage of navigator. I didn't get quite well from official docs on the other hand navigatorIOS is quite simple to use

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918666/example-of-navigation-between-views-in-react-native-android)